# support CalledVia athena condition with white-listed IP address

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-athena

This works as expected. It allows Athena to access the bucket along with other 4 white listed IP addresses.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::athenadata162",
                "arn:aws:s3:::athenadata162/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "123.456.789.120/32",
                        "234.567.889.120/32",
                        "456.789.123.456/32",
                        "567.890.123.456/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountAccessAthena",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::athenadata162",
                "arn:aws:s3:::athenadata162/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:CalledVia": "athena.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I change the * in the second statement to point to another user from some other account, then I get access denied error.

```
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/readwriteuser"
            },
```

It is possible to use "CalledVia" condition with white-listed IP addresses.
But is it possible to use the condition for some other account and also white list IP addresses?

If I keep only the second condition, then it works as expected and allow athena from another account to read data from current bucket. I am trying to allow certain known IP addresses along with Athena from another account. That does not seem to be possible. In other words...

```
IP addresses + Athena from current account = Possible
NO IP addresses + Athena from another account = Possible
IP addresses + Athena from another account = ??
```

More info:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/amazon-athena-support-querying-data-s3-buckets-aws-iam-condition-key/

Comment: have you read this ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/s3-permissions.html mentions Athena does not support restricting or allowing access to Amazon S3 resources based on the aws:SourceIp condition key

Comment: That has changed as per March 2 announcement. The "Note" is outdated.